# Sketching a plain simple gradient vector field

Tags: calculus, vectors

> Sketch the gradient vector field for $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$.

So to find the starting points of the the vector field we look at the contours of the function, in this case they are circles.

To find the gradient vector field we take the gradient of the function which is $2x\hat{i}+2y\hat{j}$.

Now if we look at vector at the point $(2,2)$ it will start from $(2,2)$ and go in the direction of $4\hat{i}+4\hat{j}$? and its magnitude will be $\sqrt{8}$?

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that its magnitude at $(x,y) = (2,2)$ is equal to 2?

Comment: @okrzysik sorry it is $\sqrt{2^2+2^2}=\sqrt{8}$ edited

Comment: Any chance you mean $\sqrt{4^2 + 4^2}$? Each component of $\nabla f$ is equal to 4 at $(2,2).$

Comment: @okrzysik  but does not the vector start at (2,2) and ends at (4,4)?

Comment: Not quite, the gradient at $(2,2)$ is equal to $4(\boldsymbol{i} + \boldsymbol{j})$, so really the vector at this point ends at $(6,6)$.